# How to check for streaks on a game board more efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

The following function receives a 2D array like so.

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'y', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'y', '.', 'r', '.', 'y'],
 ['.', 'r', 'r', 'y', 'r', 'y', 'r'],
 ['.', 'r', 'y', 'y', 'r', 'r', 'y']]
```

The purpose of the function is to count the number of "streaks" of a specified size that exist in my 2D array. A streak is defined as a consecutive line of tokens in a horizontal, vertical or diagonal arrangement.

The following example counts as 1 streak of size 2.

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', 'r', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', 'r', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

The following snippet is my brute force solution that goes through every combination of the board. Is there a more efficient solution / algorithm that I can use instead?

```
def streaks(num_repeats, board, player_color):    
    reduced_range = num_repeats - 1
    list_idx_offsets = list(range(0, num_repeats))
    counter = 0
    # Checks rows
    for col in range(0, COLUMN_COUNT - reduced_range):
        for row in range(0, ROW_COUNT):
            list_results = []
            for idx in list_idx_offsets:
                list_results.append(board[row][col + idx])
            # If the list is identical and the player is in the list, then increment counter
            if list_els_identical(list_results) and player_color in list_results:
                counter += 1
    # Checks columns
    for col in range(0, COLUMN_COUNT):
        for row in range(0, ROW_COUNT - reduced_range):
            list_results = []
            for idx in list_idx_offsets:
                list_results.append(board[row + idx][col])
            if list_els_identical(list_results) and player_color in list_results:
                counter += 1
    # Check diagonals positive
    for col in range(0, COLUMN_COUNT - reduced_range):
        for row in range(0, ROW_COUNT - reduced_range):
            list_results = []
            for idx in list_idx_offsets:
                list_results.append(board[row + idx][col + idx])
            if list_els_identical(list_results) and player_color in list_results:
                counter += 1
    # Check diagonals negative
    for col in range(0, COLUMN_COUNT - reduced_range):
        for row in range(reduced_range, ROW_COUNT):
            list_results = []
            for idx in list_idx_offsets:
                list_results.append(board[row - idx][col + idx])
            if list_els_identical(list_results) and player_color in list_results:
                counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: I would directly check if the potential streak is a streak (and stop early if you see that it is not) instead of constructing the temporary lists. You might also want to think about what you want to do about overlapping streaks. I.e., is a 3-streak equivalent to two 2-streaks? In practice, it might be slightly faster to try to extract the maximal streaks (up to a threshold) so as to avoid a few duplicated checks. But this will probably be very minor.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only x many pieces, only check for x many in a streak since there can't be more, then stop. This will be faster than checking every combination.

Answer (score 1):

- Walk the field once (by ranks or by files)

  - For each field, check for streaks (by looking at an adjacent field; if it has the same symbol then the field beyond it in the same direction etc) but only "forward": in half the directions, namely those where the fields you have not walked over yet lie.
    E.g. when walking by ranks, this will be:

    ```
    **********
    ****X-----
    .../|\....
    ../.|.\...
    ./..|..\..
    ```
- Save any found streaks to the results
- Create a matrix of flags for each field that signify which directions of those four you have already looked for a streak in from that field
- When looking for streaks from a field, for each field you looked at that had the same symbol, fill the above flags appropriately (for the current cell, fill the flags in the same manner, too). When walking over that field eventually, do not look in those directions again.

  - This will guarantee that you only have full streaks in the result rather than their parts.
- In the end, all the fields will end up with all the flags set. You can check this as a debug assertion (if not all flags are set, you failed to check the corresponding directions from the corresponding fields).